# select observation having a or A in variable

Tags: sas

dataset a like this

```
data a;
input name $;
datalines;
amAn
pArdeep
Bonaventure, T
Takahashi, Y
Derber, B
;
run;
```

How many people in dataset a have either “a” or “A” in their names,by use Index and lowcase function only.

Comment: Well you already have the functions you need. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to solve a problem on your own next time, it's too simple.

`People` is a `retained variable` and only the last observation is returned to a result table.

The simplest solution, using `countc function`, `'i' parameter` means ignore case:

```
data b;
    set a end=last;

    if countc(name, 'a', 'i') > 0 then
        people + 1; 

    if last then output;

    keep people;
end;
```

Using `index function` and `lowcase function`:

```
data b;
    set a end=last;

    if index(lowcase(name), 'a') > 0 then
        people + 1; 

    if last then output;

    keep people;
end;
```

Comment: @Joe you're right, I also noticed if you have very short variable (less than 16 characters), `countc` will be faster than `findc`, but of course `findc` is a better solution for this problem.